# Workflow 4 wait for winforms click event

Tags: winforms, workflow

I'm currently designing a workflow that displays user controls on a winforms form then waits for the user to click a button on the user control just displayed so that it can capture data the user entered. I'm having difficulty finding an activity? (is that the right word?) that sits and waits for a click event to occur on the button of the item.

Does anybody have an idea about how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: I am not clear with your question......

Comment: hmmm... In the workflow designer, is there any activity I can drop into a sequence or flowchart that, once it is reached, will wait for a certain button click event to fire before moving on?